# How to apply this 3d perspective and reflection effect on an image?

Tags: css, transform

I'm trying to apply a cross-browser perspective and reflection effect on an element (div containing an image) but no-way.

I already tried some tricks. Some are not cross-browser compliant, others just doesn't work.

This is the effect I'm looking for :

[image]

Comment: *"I already tried some tricks"*...and those were? If you tell us, we won't run the risk of recommending what you've already tried and dismissed.

Comment: Like trying to play with css perspective, perspective-origin - scale - rotate attribute
I'm not very compliant with this as I don't really understand how this stuff works